# how to filter boolean using sqldatasource parameter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, null, boolean, sqldatasource

I have the following DropDownList  :

```html
            <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderDropDownList" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Gender</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>MAle</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

and Its connected to sqlserver database table called Staff where it has (Gender) field with type (bit) ,
true means male and false means female. 
what I want is to filter using @gender parameter
here is the code behind in VB.net:

```
    StaffSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = " select Id,FullName,case when Gender = 'true'  then 'male' else 'female' end as Gender, JobTitle,PhoneNumber,Notes from Staff  where (REPLACE(FullName,' ','') LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@FullName,' ','') + '%' OR @FullName='Null') and (Gender=@Gender or @Gender='Null') order by id desc"


    StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Clear()

    'Search By FullName
    If FullNameTextBox.Text.Trim = "" Then
        StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("FullName", "Null")
    Else
        StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("FullName", FullNameTextBox.Text.Trim)
    End If

    'Search By Gender
    If GenderDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("Gender", "Null")
    ElseIf GenderDropDownList.Text.Trim = "male" Then
        StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("Gender", True)
    Else
        StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("Gender", False)
    End If

    StaffGridView.DataSourceID = "StaffSqlDataSource"
    StaffGridView.DataBind()
```

the problem is it shows this Error:
'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Null' to data type bit.
what can i do??

Comment: Why pass `True` or `False` and then use a `CASE` in your SQL when you can just pass "male" or "female" in the first place?

Comment: Hello
Using a bit type field for gender instead of varchar 
can save lots of data storage if you have millions of records

Comment: I think that the problem is in your `"Null"` parameter value try to use `DBNull.value` : If GenderDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        StaffSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("Gender", DBNull.value)